# I am getting KeyError: <class '__main__. in tkinter while trying to raise another frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am getting this error -

```
KeyError: <class '__main__.PublishPage'>
```

This is my code -

```
p = 0
#Now, Adding the different pages for the game
class HeadlineGame(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        frame = StartPage(container, self)
        self.frames[StartPage] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, controller):
        frame = self.frames[controller]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        publishbutton = tk.Button(self, image=publishimg, borderwidth=0, command= lambda: controller.show_frame(PublishPage))
        publishbutton.image = publishimg
        publishbutton.place(x=503, y=315)

class PublishPage(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
         button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Test")
         button2.grid(row=0, column=0)



app = HeadlineGame()
app.geometry('1366x768')
app.mainloop()
```

I have tried to resolve the issue but to no avail.
Is this a problem with the lambda command? 
I want it so that when I push the button, it takes me to the second frame, even if this specific issue cannot be resolved is there a way to achieve that?

Thank you.

**EDIT** traceback error:

```
> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",
> line 1883, in __call__
>     return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Python\intro.py", line 276, in <lambda>
>     publishbutton = tk.Button(self, image=publishimg, borderwidth=0, command= lambda: controller.show_frame(PublishPage))   File
> "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Python\intro.py", line 197, in show_frame
>     frame = self.frames[controller] KeyError: <class '__main__.PublishPage'>
```

Comment: can you share the Traceback (error) logs which you get after executing the code ?

Comment: xception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Python\intro.py", line 276, in <lambda>
    publishbutton = tk.Button(self, image=publishimg, borderwidth=0, command= lambda: controller.show_frame(PublishPage))
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Python\intro.py", line 197, in show_frame
    frame = self.frames[controller]
KeyError: <class '__main__.PublishPage'>
[Finished in 2.2s]

Comment: You haven't done `self.frames[PublishPage] = ...` anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest refactoring things like this. `show_frame()` will now take care of instantiating a new frame upon request; you don't have to manage `self.frames` yourself.

```py
class HeadlineGame(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.container = container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, controller):
        if controller not in self.frames:
            self.frames[controller] = frame = controller(self.container, self)
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        frame = self.frames[controller]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        publishbutton = tk.Button(
            self, image=publishimg, borderwidth=0, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PublishPage)
        )
        publishbutton.image = publishimg
        publishbutton.place(x=503, y=315)


class PublishPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Test")
        button2.grid(row=0, column=0)


app = HeadlineGame()
app.geometry("1366x768")
app.mainloop()
```